# vega stacked bar syntax for "y2" field in properties

Tags: vega, vincent

Can someone explain to me the following line in the vincent docs for a stacked bar:

https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent/blob/master/examples/stacked_bar_examples.py

```
y2=ValueRef(field='y2', scale='y')
```

I don't see any field called "y2" in the data set so I am confused as to where it is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `y2` field is generated by the Vega `stack` transform ([code here](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/v1.x/src/data/stack.js)).

<strike>In Vega, The `rect` mark can be defined by `y`+`y2` or `y`+`height`.  See [Marks#Shared Visual Properties](https://github.com/vega/vega/wiki/Marks#shared-visual-properties) in Vega's docs:</strike>

> For marks involving Cartesian extents (e.g., **rect** marks), the
>   horizontal dimensions are determined by (in order of precedence) the x
>   and x2 properties, the x and width properties, and the x2 and width
>   properties. If all three of x, x2 and width are specified, the width
>   value is ignored. **The y, y2 and height properties are treated
>   similarly.**

Check out the [stacked bar demo in the Vega Live Editor](https://trifacta.github.io/vega/editor/index.html?spec=stacked_bar), which includes:

```
...
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "properties": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "data.x"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": true, "offset": -1},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y2"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "data.c"}
        },
        "update": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
...
```

Try changing `y2` with `height` in the live editor.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand what y2 is (i.e. y= bottom, y2= top, x=left, x2 = right) but where does its value come from?  It's a variable, where is it generated?  Also, when I sub "height" for "y2" the graph doesn't render...

Comment: @Skorp I figured this out after answering :-)  Answer updated.

Comment: thanks! that solves the mystery.  I'll try to decipher the code